# Django does not load internal .css files

Tags: python, css, django, uwsgi, cherokee

I have created a Django project in local which runs without any kind of problem. But, after an annoying and difficult Cherokee + uWSGI installation on Amazon AWS, my project does not show Django .css internal files.

http://f.cl.ly/items/2Q2W3I3R0X1n2X3v0q2P/django_error.jpg <-- `/Admin/` looks like this

The image is a screen of my /admin/, which should have a different style, but .css files are not loaded.

```
[pid: 23206|app: 0|req: 19/19] 83.49.10.217 () {56 vars in 1121 bytes} [Sun Apr 15      05:50:24 2012] GET /static/admin/css/base.css => generated 2896 bytes in 6 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 1 headers in 51 bytes (1 switches on core 0)

[pid: 23206|app: 0|req: 20/20] 83.49.10.217 () {56 vars in 1125 bytes} [Sun Apr 15 05:50:24 2012] GET /static/admin/css/login.css => generated 2899 bytes in 5 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 1 headers in 51 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

This is a log from Cherokee. I don't understand why it is looking for the .css files in that path. Cherokee should be searching the files in Django original directory so I didn't change .css files in my project.

Any advice? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using Django 1.4 in which this is the expected behavior.

Checkout the Backwards incompatible changes section in [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/):

> The included administration app django.contrib.admin has for a long
>   time shipped with a default set of static files such as JavaScript,
>   images and stylesheets. Django 1.3 added a new contrib app
>   django.contrib.staticfiles to handle such files in a generic way and
>   defined conventions for static files included in apps.
>
> Starting in Django 1.4, the admin's static files also follow this
>   convention, to make the files easier to deploy. In previous versions
>   of Django, it was also common to define an ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX setting
>   to point to the URL where the admin's static files live on a Web
>   server. This setting has now been deprecated and replaced by the more
>   general setting STATIC_URL. Django will now expect to find the admin
>   static files under the URL /admin/.
>
> If you've previously used a URL path for ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX (e.g.
>   /media/) simply make sure STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT are configured
>   and your Web server serves those files correctly. The development
>   server continues to serve the admin files just like before. Read the
>   static files howto for more details.
>
> If your ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX is set to an specific domain (e.g.
>   http://media.example.com/admin/), make sure to also set your
>   STATIC_URL setting to the correct URL -- for example,
>   http://media.example.com/.*

Comment: Thanks! All have been solved. I didn't know static files system had changed in Django 1.4.